# Finding last entry in a foreach() process

Tags: php, foreach

Simple one guys.

I have an XML parsed using simplexml_load_file().

The following code:

```
<?php
    foreach($xml->actors->actor as $actors) {
        echo $actors.", ";
    }
?>
```

Gives the following result:

```
John Smith, Amy Adams, Charlie Doe,
```

How do I modify the code such that it gives:

```
John Smith, Amy Adams, Charlie Doe
```

This needs to apply across any number of entries in the array. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try [This solution](http://blog.actsmedia.com/2009/09/php-foreach-last-item-last-loop/) ?

Comment: Okay, next (very basic) question:

How do I assign the result for the above foreach() to a variable, so I can just call the variable later on to keep the code tidy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [implode](http://php.net/implode) function.

```
echo implode(", ", $xml->actors->actor);
```

Comment: It seems there's a consensus! Thanks all - didn't know such a function existed.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the current index in a foreach:

```
<?php
    foreach($xml->actors->actor as $key => $actors) {
     if ($key == (count($actors)-1) echo "Last entry!";
    }
?>
```

In cases like this, however, I prefer to create a temporary array with the entries first, and then implode it:

```
echo implode(",", $names);
```

Comment: It would be great for building SQL queries if there was something like implode that allows prefixing and suffixing.

Comment: You can get index (as integer) only if the array is not associative.

Comment: @2astalavista you're right. I can't fix this right now, I may delete it later.

Answer (score 1):

```
print implode(',',$xml->actors->actor);
```

Comment: FYI: The difference between echo & print is that print returns a value if it is able to output its content, whereas echo has no return value. So, you can say if(print('abc')), but not if(echo('xyz'))

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this problem with a simple array:

```
<?php
$names = array();
foreach($xml->actors->actor as $actors) {
    $names[] = $actors;
}
echo implode(", ", $names);
?>
```

As a matter of fact why not just say

```
<?php
    echo implode(", ", $xml->actors->actor);
?>
```

Comment: 1) foreach($xml->actors->actor as $actors) {echo $actors.", ";}
2) echo implode(',',$xml->actors->actor);

Ran into a snag. First one outputs correctly, second one gives me an "invalid arguments" error. Any ideas? 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can either implode the array as many people above have suggested, or assign the actor's names to a variable and concatenate that variable with each iteration, and then perform a rtrim operation on the resulting array to remove the last comma.

But for simplicity's sake, go with an implode.